# Why does sending retainCount to @"Hi" return -1?

Tags: objective-c, types, retaincount

The method `retainCount` is supposed to return an unsigned integer.

Why then, does `[@"Hi" retainCount]` return -1?

Comment: /me facepalms.  `retainCount` is never useful to inspect yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simple answer is that because `@"Hi`" is a string literal, it will always be sitting around in the binary executable image, and will never "go away", thus retain/release have no effect, and you're seeing `UINT_MAX` (which looks like -1 when printed out signed eg with %d). (See Pete Kirkham's answer about NSObjects having these semantics).

Beyond this, it's useful to know that although @"Hi" behaves like an `NSString*`, it's actually a compiler-created instance of the class `CFConstantString` (or possibly NSConstantString, my debugger doesn't agree with some documentation), which wraps the literal string data and gives you the NSString* interface on it. But the compiler knows that these strings are special and can't ever get cleaned up, so they will always have a retainCount of UINT_MAX (-1)

Answer (score 6):

According to Apple's [NSObject documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount), it should return `UINT_MAX` for objects which never get released. If you print `UINT_MAX` as a signed int, you typically get `-1`, which may be what you're doing - how are you outputting the value?

Comment: That's for signed integers. Use `%zu` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Don't ever rely on the `retainCount` method. Cocoa makes all sorts of optimisations behind-the-scenes which makes the `retainCount` method unreliable and useless. Even Apple discourages using it. Stick to the memory management rules set out for Cocoa and you'll never need to know the `retainCount` of any object.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between signed and unsigned integers is how you interpret the value.  If read -1 as an unsigned int you'll find that it is the maximum value for an unsigned int.

For example: `NSLog(@"%u", [@"Hello" retainCount]);`

The reason it's such a large value is because constant string objects are never deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

@"Hello" is not required to release with code ,

just be care for the object was create by "alloc" other no memory leak issue