# How to release NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How do we release NSString that is not alloc or evern other objects?

Example:

```
NSString *test = @"testing";
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is somewhat a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069459/does-some-text-give-an-autoreleased-or-retain-1-object-back

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't. You just release the objects you own. You own the object if you used alloc, copy or new keywords when instantiating them.

Comment: Why would I need to alloc an object ?

Comment: @iosdevnyc - There are some initializer methods that don't have corresponding "convenience" creation methods. Aside from that, it's mostly a matter of using whichever style is a better fit for the ownership pattern you need. If you're going to assign the object to a retained property, for example, the property accessor will establish the ownership claim, so using a convenience constructor is easier than an alloc/init/assign/release series.

Comment: `NSString *howOld = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"I am %d years old", myAge];` - string values known at compile time are not alloc'd, those you create programmatically are