# How do I properly release NSMutableDictionary objects copied from one array to another?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

In the following code I want to traverse an NSMutableArray (self.codes) which contains NSMutableDictionary objects. If the value for the "selected" key is equal to "1" then I want to copy the NSMutableDictionary "code" object and add it to the selectedCodes array.

```
1  -(NSMutableArray *)getSelecedCodes{
2  
3  NSMutableArray *selectedCodes=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
4  
5  for (NSMutableDictionary *code in self.codes) {
6    if([code valueForKey:@"selected"]==@"1"){
7      [selectedCodes addObject:[code copy]];
8    }
9  }
10
11 return selectedCodes;
12
13 }
```

When I analyze the code in XCode I get a warning of the potential memory leaks. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare NSString's. Use `-isEqualToString:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-[NSMutableArray addObject:]` retains its argument. `copy` returns a retained value as well. So you're retaining the copied dictionary *twice*.

You probably want to do this:

```
[selectedCodes addObject:[[code copy] autorelease]];
```

However, depending on your specific needs, there are a couple caveats:

1. Are you sure you want to copy the dictionary? You can just add it to the array:

   `[selectedCodes addObject:code];`

   Note that both `selectedCodes` and `self.codes` will contain pointers to the same dictionary, so changes in one copy will be reflected in the other as well.
2. You might want to create a *mutable* copy of the dictionary. `copy` returns an immutable object:

   `[selectedCodes addObject:[[code mutableCopy] autorelease]];`

Answer (score 3):

You should autorelease the copied object as you add it

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *code in self.codes) {
    if([code valueForKey:@"selected"]==@"1"){
        [selectedCodes addObject:[[code copy] autorelease]];  
    }
}
```

You should also use the string comparing methods as opposed to simple pointer comparison:

```
[code valueForKey:@"selected"]==@"1"
```

will never be true, instead use

```
[[code valueForKey:@"selected"] isEqualToString:@"1"]
```

Comment: Literal strings aren't autoreleased -- they're actually immortal, and the best way to think of them is _unowned_.

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks for pointing that out, found a few SO posts on the subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069459/does-some-text-give-an-autoreleased-or-retain-1-object-back. Didn't know they just lived forever.

Comment: Welcome! It's interesting -- I think it's done because they're actually objects (`NSConstantString`) and it's way simpler to put them in the data segment of the binary than to fuss around with managing heap memory as if it were on the stack.