# Objective-C: What is the significance of the "@" (at) symbol for NSLog (@"abc");?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nslog, directive

And also, why is it not necessary for, eg:

```
printf ("abc")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSLog` takes an `NSString` as argument. `@"abc"` denotes an `NSString` because of the @ sign, so that is a valid argument for `NSLog`. `printf` is a normal C function that takes a C string, which is simply created using "".

Comment: `@"abc"` is short for `[NSString stringWithString:@"abc"]` ?? This would be a recursive definition.

Comment: @MartinR: You are correct! I believe it is `stringWithCString:encoding`, but feel free to correct me.

Comment: `@"abc"` creates a `NSString` object at compile time, it does not call `stringWithCString` or similar at runtime.

Comment: @JamesBoutcher: I think `@"abc"` is called a *string literal*. Boxing is `@(c-string)`.

Comment: `@"this is my string"` isn't _short_ for anything. It creates a literal `NSString` object that the compiler bakes right in to the binary. See, for example "[Does @"some text" give an autoreleased or retain 1 object back?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6069459)".

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE:
 NSLog(@"%@",dictionary)
```

Tells the compiler that i got string to fulfill the requirement of string argument.

Update: Sorry I was supposed to write the "NSLog" instead of printf. my mistake!

Comment: This does not work at all. Depending on your compiler settings, it will not compile, produce warnings, or give wrong results.  `printf` does not accept an `NSString` as format string, and `printf` does not know the `%@` format.

Answer (score 1):

Because it requires NSString. Adding @declares value as type of NSObject (simplification).